# streamWrite doesn't work

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm trying to read file into a string and rewrite that string into a new file, but there is a small check, if the current character is one of special characters that I want to rewrite.
I've debugged it, and the code seems to work fine, but the output file is empty.. I think I'm missing something... but what?

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(newname, true);

char current;
int j;
string CyrAlph = "йцукен";
string LatAlph = "ysuken";
string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);

for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (CyrAlph.IndexOf(text[i]) != -1)
    {
        j = CyrAlph.IndexOf(text[i]);
        current = LatAlph[j];

    }
    else current = text[i];

    file.Write(current);
}
```

Comment: First, close your file. Inserting _Stream file = ..._ into a _using()_

Comment: I've rewrited it:
    `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newname))
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (CyrAlph.IndexOf(text[i]) != -1)
                    {
                        j = CyrAlph.IndexOf(text[i]);
                        current = LatAlph[j];

                    }
                    else current = text[i];

                    sw.Write(current);
                    //sw.AutoFlush = true;
                }
            }
`
is it OK? it works, but I'm afraid, if it's good way of programming?

Comment: this is THE preferred way to write the code....it guarantees proper disposal

Comment: so, I don't need to close the file?

Comment: @hurremdev When it leaves the using body, it automatically flushes and closes the file. Take a look to my answer to have the code with using. But what you have written seems to be good.

Comment: The using statement will dispose the StreamWriter which will close the file.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set `file.AutoFlush = true` after your `StreamWriter` instantiation or call `file.Close` at the end of writing everything or you can instantiate your StreamWriter in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement. My guess is that it is empty because the buffer needs flushed

Comment: this didn't work.. may be I used it not correctly, I just tryed to add this code right after file.Write(current).

Answer (score 0):

`StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable`. You "have" to `Dispose` it after using it. To do so, use a `using` statement. This will automatically flushes and closes the stream at the end of the `using` body.

```
using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(newname,true))
{
    char current;
    int j;
    string CyrAlph="йцукен";
    string LatAlph = "ysuken";
    string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (CyrAlph.IndexOf(text[i]) != -1)
        {
            j=CyrAlph.IndexOf(text[i]);
            current = LatAlph[j];

        }
        else current=text[i];

        file.Write(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a stream flush. The standard pattern is to add a `using` statement around the allocation of the StreamWriter. That also takes care of closing the file and releasing the operating system's file handle:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
   // Work with your file here

} // After this block, you have "disposed" of the file object.
  // That takes care of flushing the stream and releasing the file handle
```

The using statement has the added benefit, over explicitly closing the stream, of disposing the stream correctly even in the case of an exception within the block.